# Swift UIButton edge insets

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uibutton

I am trying to make a square button that is on the smaller side (30x30), and I want to include the amount of participants there are as the text, for some reason the button is cutting the title off on the left and ride sides (see picture) forcing me to either have a bigger button (not ideal) or have really small text (also not ideal). Is there a way to stop it from cutting off?

[image]

Comment: Show the relevant code.

Comment: @Magnas it is storyboard, no code

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to display one character in that 30*30 button, make the button size `large`, check screenshots for reference:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Change Button Style **Plain** into **Default**.

[image]